# Other than inheriting from the appropriate classes, what additional steps need to be taken to create a custom table cell in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

More specifically, I have created a CollectionView which contains a CollectionViewCell in it. Within my CollectionViewController code is the:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

function which does the whole dequeuing cells thing for me. I have traced my program, and it crashes at this line (it sends me to the assembler code):

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
```

However, When I change "CustomCell" to "UICollectionViewCell" it works perfectly. This was odd to me because my CustomCell class has adopted the properties of UICollectionViewCell, as seen in these lines:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

I have also set the reuseIdentifier in both the initialisation of this view and within the storyboard. My question is: when creating custom cells for table/collection views, what additional steps need to be taken?

EDIT: This is the specific crashing screen:
[image: Crash screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register, either the Nib or the Class as a cell for reuse identifier. In code use these methods:

```
func registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass!, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String!)
func registerNib(_ nib: UINib!, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String!)
```

The crash is due to as operator returning an optional. It is force-unwrapped and crashes because the identifier is not registered for your class, thus the cell is UICollectionViewCell, not your custom class.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338